# JavaScript extend "referenceerror: can't find variable that"

Tags: javascript, closures, extend

My brain isn't working this morning – it's been a little while since I did JavaScript.  Here's the tiny-example:

```
function foobar() {
  var that = this;
}
foobar.prototype.bletch = function() { console.log(that) }
xyzzy = new foobar();
xyzzy.bletch();
```

Gives: `ReferenceError: can't find variable: that`

I could have done this by:

```
extend(foobar, { bletch: function() ... } );
```

So, what is the right way to write this?  I need to be able to externally call methods of this object/function and to have it remember what `this` was at the time it was created.  (I *know* this is a dumb-question.)

I am *not* using a package like JQuery, and can't do so.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... putting it *inside* the function worked:

```
function foo() {
  var that = this;

  this.bar = function() { console.log(that) }
}

zoo = new foo();
zoo.bar()
```

*"It's all com-ing back to me now ..."*